# Can you enchant player characters' prosthetics permanently?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, player-characters

I understand that there's a huge difference between people and magical items, but the focus of this is on creating permanent magical enhancement on prosthetics itself and seeing how far you can push it.

For example, say you have a PC who's lost an eye and is looking to replace it with a prosthetic eye... could they have truesight permanently cast upon the eye to give it usefulness and grant the user partial truesight though that eye? Or for a smaller example, have a special magic cast on a prosthetic arm to regive the user a sense of touch through that arm?

In other words: **Are prosthetics too permanently attached to a player character to be considered a potential magical item?**

EDIT: I've discovered [Ersatz Eye](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/xgte/common-magic-items#ErsatzEye), which kind of answers my question, though I am still wondering if such magical items can be further enchanted, or if their name removes such an ability?

Comment: @MikeQ That would be another way to go about it. I was thinking that the loss of a limb would be detrimental to a character and wondered if there was a way to use magical items to compensate the loss (knowing people would like to upgrade rather than just compensate)

Comment: Do not answer in comments.

Comment: There's a canonical answer to this now, thanks to the new Eberron book, hence my vote to reopen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## It's up to the DM

[Crafting magic items](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/xgte/downtime-revisited#CraftinganItem) is entirely up to the DM as to what works and what's needed.

It's an optional rule and not something that's part of the core.

Many tables don't allow it at all and others may, but all varying by DM Fiat.  Any questions on what's possible with this will always be up to the DM.